# Proving that for structure $M=(\mathbb R; +,<,0)$, the function $f(x,y)=x \cdot y$ is not a definable set in $M$

Tags: model-theory

Proving that for structure $M=(\mathbb R; +,<,0)$, the function $f(x,y)=x \cdot y$ is not a definable set in $M$.

Note: A function is called a definable set, if its graph, meaning the set $(x,f(x)), x \in M $ (the structure's universe) is a definable set in the structure.

So in this case we need to prove the set $(x,y,x \cdot y)$ is not definable in $M$. Using the last section in the Wikipedia article on a definable set, we know that if $X$ is definable on structure $M$ over parameters $c_1, \cdots, c_s$  then for every automorphism $\alpha: M \rightarrow M$ so that for every parameter $\alpha(c_i)=c_i$ , if $(x_1, x_2,..) \in X$ then $(\alpha(x_1), \alpha (x_2),..) \in X$ as well.

So to show that the function is not definable without parameters, we can assume it is definable, then look at the homomorphism $\alpha(x)=2x$ and see it isn't invariant, as $(2,3,6)\in X$, however $(4,6,12) \not\in X$.

What I try to do now for a really long time is proving it is not definable with parameters as well. Any help will be great!

**Idea I thought of, not sure if correct.** Lets assume $X$ is definable over parameters $c_1,...,c_s$. $\mathbb R$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. Lets set $V_1=\text{span} \{c_1, c_2, ..., c_s\}$. So we know there is some $V_2$ so that $\mathbb R=V_1 \oplus V_2$. And for every $r \in \mathbb R$, there are unique $v_1 \in V_1, v_2 \in V_2$ so that $r=v_1+v_2$.

So lets set a homomorphism like so: $\alpha(r)=\alpha(v_1+v_2)=v_1+2v_2$. It indeed preserves $<$ and $+$, so it is a homomorphism. And for every $c_i \in V_1$, $\alpha(c_i)=c_i$, so it's invariant over the parameters. The only question is whether, for $a_1,a_2 \in V_2$, $a_1 \cdot a_2 \in V_2$. Because, if so, we can look at $\alpha(a_1 \cdot a_2)=2a_1a_2$, while $\alpha(a_1)\cdot \alpha(a_2)=4a_1a_2$, thus showing $X$ is not definable.

Comment: I don't see why it would preserve $<$...

Comment: In fact I'm certain it doesn't preserve $<$. If $f$ is an automorphism of that structure then there exists a non-zero $c$ such that $f(x)=cx$ for all $x$.

Comment: I see... Then my question remains. We haven't been taught another method to refute definabilty, so it is really weird there are no automorphisms here.

Comment: As long as nobody who knows a solution is giving any hints, here's a probably useless thought. That mapping of yours _is_ an automorphism of $(\mathbb R,+)$, so it shows multiplication is not definable with parameters in _that_ structure. Now, it's also a fact that $<$ is definable in $(\mathbb R, +,*)$, where $*$ denotes multiplication. Hence (???????????) if multiplication were definable with parameters in the original structure it would also be so in $(\mathbb R,+)$ ??? Just a thought, for the little it's worth...

Comment: Another thought, probably irrelevant but perhaps interesting. Let's just talk about the _positive_ reals to avoid irrelevant complications. Multiplication _is_ definable via an infinite set of formulas, using only the parameter $1$. Note first that for a given rational $r$ the relation $r<x$ is definable. For example, $2/3<x$ is defined by $1+1<x+x+x$. Now for two positive rationals $r$ and $s$ consider the formulas $r<x\wedge s<y\implies rs<z$ and $r>x\wedge s>y\implies rs>z$. Multiplication is defined by the set of all such formulas.

Comment: Your structure is an ordered divisible abelian group which admits quantifier elimination - See Marker's book. So the only definable subsets of plane are boolean combinations of linear equations and inequalities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As hot_queen notes in the comments, you can show this using quantifier elimination. But the idea the you suggested will actually work! The problem was that any collection of parameters from $\mathbb{R}$ control all of $\mathbb{R}$ (as in David Ullrich's answer) - you don't have the flexibility of automorphisms that you'd like. The solution is to leave $\mathbb{R}$ behind and move to an elementary extension which is more flexible.

Pick some elementary extension $\langle \mathbb{R}^*;+,<,0\rangle$ of $\mathbb{R}$ which contains "infinite elements", i.e. realize the type $\{x > r\mid r\in \mathbb{R}\}$. Now let $V_1$ be the convex hull of $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathbb{R}^*$: $$V_1 = \{x\mid \exists r_1, r_2\in\mathbb{R}, r_1 < x < r_2\}.$$
Notice that $V_1$ is not all of $\mathbb{R}^*$ (since there are infinite elements), but $V_1$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-subspace of $\mathbb{R}^*$. So we can write $\mathbb{R}^* = V_1\oplus V_2$ and decompose any element $r\in\mathbb{R}^*$ as $r = v_1 + v_2$ with $v_1\in V_1$ and $v_2\in V_2$.

Consider, just as you suggested, the map $\alpha(r) = v_1 + 2v_2$.
$\alpha$ is clearly an invertible linear map which fixed $\mathbb{R}$ but is not the identity on $\mathbb{R}^*$. And this time it respects $<$.

[Why? If $r < r'$, then writing $r = v_1 + v_2$ and $r' = v_1' + v_2'$, we have that $r' - r = (v_2' - v_2) + (v_1' - v_1) > 0$. Since $v_2' - v_2\notin V_1$, it's either positive and greater than everything in $V_1$ or negative and less than everything in $V_1$. Well, it must be positive since the sum is positive, so also $\alpha(r') - \alpha(r) = 2(v_2' - v_2) + (v_1'-v_1) > 0$, and $\alpha(r) < \alpha(r')$.]

Now suppose multiplication is definable in $\mathbb{R}$. We can use the same formula to define a multiplication function on $\mathbb{R}^*$ with the same first-order properties (since $\mathbb{R}^*$ is an elementary extension). Take $r\in V_2$ with $r>0$. Since multiplication by a positive element is an increasing function, and $r$ is greater than every element of $\mathbb{R}$, the same is true of $r^2$. Then $(\alpha(r))^2 = (2r)^2 = 4r^2$, but $\alpha(r^2) \leq 2r^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't show that multiplication is not definable with parameters, but it shows that the first approach you mention can't work. (Unless I'm still confused. Thanks to Asaf for straightening me out here, unless it turns out he didn't, in which case it's my fault...)

Say multiplication is definable with parameters from $X$. We can't have $X=\{0\}$, because $0$ is definable without parameters so that would imply that multiplication was definable without parameters. So $X$ must contain something nonzero. But:

Fact: If $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is a homomorphism of that structure, $t\ne0$, and $f(t)=t$ then $f(x)=x$ for all $x$.

Proof: It's well known that the condition $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ implies that $f$ is either a straight line or very bad (for example non-measurable). Our $f$ is monotone, hence not so bad, hence a straight line. And now $f(t)=t$ gives qed.

Comment: Just because there are no automorphisms doesn't mean that something is definable. Definable with parameters means that you simply allow a formula $\varphi(x,y,z,u_1,\ldots,u_n)$, such that for some fixed $r_1,\ldots,r_n\in\Bbb R$, $\Bbb R\models\varphi(x,y,z,r_1,\ldots,r_n)$ if and only if $xy=z$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oh, thanks. Regarding whether to edit or delete: It's still true that the nonexistence of those automorphisms implies that the method the OP says (s)he has been trying to use can't work, yes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Although you haven't quite established that if for *some* $t\neq0$, $f(t)=t$, then $f(1)=1$, though.

Comment: Added a suggestion for a solution